# We have a requirement where i have to close the browser tab when user logout of Salesforce

Tags: logout

We have a requirement where i have to close the browser tab when user logout of Salesforce. How this can be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

Try this, if this is a real requirement. There would be some kind of customization required here.

In `Session Settings` you have an option to add a Custom logout URL.

[image]

You can host a html which will have a `window.close();` written in script.
And give the URL in the `Logout URL`. So that when logout happens, salesforce redirects you to the custom html and the javascript code should close the window.

I hosted a localhost app. and added this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<script>
    window.close();
</script>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

And in logout URL added. And it closes the window when I logout of Salesforce.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Nagendra, let me try this. Yes, this is actual requirement. We have requirement to enable SSO only for community users but the internal users should have both SF login as well as SSO login. So need to have a common log off page for both internal and community users (and it cannot be SSO login page or SF login page). Hence we were looking to see if we can close the browser tab itself. Do you have any other suggestion based on the requirement mentioned above?